# How can I test whether a single character is lower case in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I want to implement a small routine that generates the plural form of the name of an entity in Spanish. Basically, it takes a WordInCSharpCase or a wordInJavaCase, such as `MedioDePago` (payment method), and it appends an "s" at right before the first non-lowercase character (excluding the first character), which in this case would produce the string `MediosDePago` (payment methods). In C#, this routine was:

```
public string Pluralize(string input)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (++i < input.Length)
        if (!char.IsLower(input[i]))
            break;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
    builder.Insert(i, 's');
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Now I need to implement this routine in PHP, but I cannot find an equivalent of C#'s `char.IsLower`. The only thing I have found is `ctype_lower`, but it takes a *string* as an input, and creating/testing/discarding several strings would be too inefficient. Does PHP have a function that tests whether a single character is in lower case?

Comment: Does it need to be able to accept international characters?

Comment: No. Not even Spanish's ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú. Just the 26 standard English letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, creating several strings is not inefficient.  A string is a native type in PHP and it's quite efficient at doing it.  What I would do is something like this:

```
$callback = function($match) {
    return $match[1] . 's' . $match[2];
};

$string = preg_replace_callback('/^([A-Za-z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', $callback, $string);
```

Or, as @Kevin suggests in the comments:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^([A-Za-z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', '\1s\2', $string);
```

It's more efficient since it doesn't need to capture past the first non-lowercase character.

Comment: He only needs the first match according to his data, so the callback in overkill. Otherwise, this is what I would have done.

Comment: Wow. I never understood regular expressions (mainly because I never actually tried), but I'm beginning to appreciate their power.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct myself. I misunderstood what this was doing at first :P I was thinking of using `preg_replace` without a callback. Such as: `preg_replace( '/^([A-Za-z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', "\\1s\\2", $string );`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a `string` and a `char` so using `ctype_lower()` is absolutely OK. In fact there isn't even a real `string` in PHP, a `string` in PHP is merely a blob of binary data.

I actually don't know if `ctype_lower()` can deal with extended character sets and characters outside the ASCII range. If that's a requirement, you must perhaps use the PCRE unicode capabilities to check fo lower-case characters outside the ASCII range.

Comment: How can I retrieve a single character of a string **without** creating a new string?

Comment: @Eduardo: you can't.  But it's not a big deal to create a new string.  PHP is quite smart in its memory management and dealings with strings...

Comment: You're always creating a new string in PHP - but that really isn't a problem. Even if you extract a single character via `$string[3]` for example, you'll internally create a new string variable. PHP is not Java or C# where strings are immutable objects and creating new strings is a problem. Strings are of an internal datatype like integers or floats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/mb_strtolower) for this, like so:

```
$a = 'a';
var_dump(mb_strtolower($a, "UTF-8") == $a); // bool(true)

$b = 'A';
var_dump(mb_strtolower($b, "UTF-8") == $b); // bool(false)
```