# Obtaining the plural form of a class name using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

A while ago, [I asked for a function to convert a Spanish class names into plural forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263271/how-can-i-test-whether-a-single-character-is-lower-case-in-php):

```
function pluralize($element) {
    return preg_replace('/^([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', '\1s\2', $element);
}
```

For example, a class representing a invoice item line (Spanish: *línea de detalle de (la) factura*) could be called `LineaDetalleFactura`, and its plural would be `LineasDetalleFactura`.

Now, I would like to modify this function to take into consideration that plurals of words that end in consonants are formed by adding "es" instead of "s".

For example, a class representing a payment order (Spanish: *orden de pago*) could be called `OrdenPago`, and its plural should be `OrdenesPago`.

Any ideas on how I could do this using regular expressions?

Comment: Can you link us to the original question?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Unfortunately, I cannot find the question.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I could do it the brute-force way, using an algorithm that pretends PHP understand characters. But, unfortunately, PHP does not understand characters.

Comment: @Eduardo: "PHP does not understand characters"?  What do you mean?  Incidentally, I think that the solution you're imagining is not "brute-force", but probably the correct way to do this sort of ad-hoc string manipulation.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I mean PHP has no character datatype. The only way to process "characters" in PHP is to create ad-hoc one-character strings ("oy vey, PHP is today's VBA"), which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Eduardo: I'm not sure that's a problem.  If you use e.g. the Ctype functions (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php), you'll probably get a long way.

Comment: @Eduardo: PHP doesn't have a distinct "type" for single characters, that's true. But I can't fathom why this is a problem when you have single-character strings.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The assembly programmer in me cannot stand writing programs that generate lots of one-character strings.

Comment: @Eduardo: The assembly programmer in you should accept that PHP is a _much_ higher-level language... and move on. If you knew what went into PHP strings you'd probably have a coronary. :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not easily solvable. With a regular expression you can address perhaps 80-85% of the cases.

In some words, the plural form does not change; the plural of *crisis* is also *crisis*. Also, there are exceptions for words ending in *é*; the plural of *café* is *cafés*.

You also have words that have their own rules like *mamá* and *papá* (the plural forms are *mamás* and *papás* respectively).

Finally, you have words where you need to adjust the accents properly. For example, the plural of *examen* is *exámenes* (the accent is on the *a*).

I found a pretty good summarization of pluralization-rules in Spanish [here](http://spanish.about.com/cs/writing/a/writing_plurals.htm), which should help you out.

Your best bet is to build a map of exceptions and their plurals. Then, check to see if the word you are pluralizing exists in that list. If it does, you can simply grab its plural from the map. If the word doesn't exist in the map, then it is a word to which you can apply pluralization rules to figure out the plural (the page I linked to earlier, should help you out). The hard part is building the list of exceptions; if you can narrow-down your list (i.e, exclude words that are not likely to be used) then you job will be much easier.

Comment: I am a native Spanish speaker and also a grammar Nazi (or should I say Francoist?), so I _do_ know how write properly in it. I just happen to be writing a Web Service whose responses are collections of items. And, since I am _incredibly_ lazy, I do not want to manually specify collection types, like, for example, `OrdenesDePago` (collection of `OrdenDePago` items). So I want to implement a tool that generates the collection types for me. / Also, I know I have to use an explicit list of pluralization exceptions. I just want that list to be as short as possible.

Comment: @Eduardo didn't mean to suggest that you didn't know Spanish :) I was just saying that you will need an exception list. Also yes, if the list is as short as possible then it would be easier. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function pluralize($element) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/^([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', function($args) {
        // If the first word ends in consonant, append "e" first. After that, append "s".
        return preg_replace('/([B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z])$/i', '\1e', $args[1]) . "s{$args[2]}";
    }, $element);
}
```